# Vector graphic as button icon

Tags: silverlight, templates, styling, vector-graphics

Doing this in Silverlight seems harder than it should be and I also don't have a 100% solution.  I have a handful of vector icons created by my designer.  I import these into Expression Design.  The all come in as one sheet of icons where I select one icon and it's parts, do Part Operations > Unite, right-click > export, and choose "XAML Silverlight 4 / WPF Canvas".  The file it creates looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="Document" Width="36.0254" Height="38.3402" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 36.0254,0L 36.0254,38.3402L 0,38.3402L 0,0">
    <Canvas x:Name="Layer_1" Width="799.564" Height="600.326" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
    <Path x:Name="Path" Width="36.1326" Height="38.3401" Canvas.Left="-0.000118291" Canvas.Top="2.00272e-005" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 28.1747,10.0387C 28.1747,15.5867 23.6801,20.0827 18.1321,20.0827C 12.5881,20.0827 8.09204,15.5867 8.09204,10.0387C 8.09204,4.49471 12.5881,2.00272e-005 18.1321,2.00272e-005C 23.6801,2.00272e-005 28.1747,4.49471 28.1747,10.0387 Z M 10.0131,19.6989C 10.0131,19.6989 17.9891,27.2895 25.9651,19.6989C 25.9651,19.6989 37.6877,26.0415 35.9584,38.3402L 0.115723,38.3402C 0.115723,38.3402 -1.80688,26.6162 10.0131,19.6989 Z "/>
</Canvas>
```

I then pull out just the path geometry and throw that into the Style of a ContentControl and put that into a resource dictionary.  It looks thus:

```
<Style x:Key="UserIcon" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Path Stretch="Uniform" Fill="White" Data="F1 M 28.1747,10.0387C 28.1747,15.5867 23.6801,20.0827 18.1321,20.0827C 12.5881,20.0827 8.09204,15.5867 8.09204,10.0387C 8.09204,4.49471 12.5881,2.00272e-005 18.1321,2.00272e-005C 23.6801,2.00272e-005 28.1747,4.49471 28.1747,10.0387 Z M 10.0131,19.6989C 10.0131,19.6989 17.9891,27.2895 25.9651,19.6989C 25.9651,19.6989 37.6877,26.0415 35.9584,38.3402L 0.115723,38.3402C 0.115723,38.3402 -1.80688,26.6162 10.0131,19.6989 Z " />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Finally, the button looks like:

```
<Button>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource UserIcon" />
</Button>
```

That works OK, but a) it's a hassle, and b) it's limited in one critical way.  I want the ability to change the color for things like hover and active.  The problem is template binding doesn't work.  I.e. I cannot do:

```
<Path Stretch="Uniform" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" ...
```

The "TemplateBinding" choice not only doesn't show up in the VS.Net editor but it simply applies no color at all if I just try it (ignoring VS.Net's suggestion that it doesn't work).  So as it is now I have to define an entirely separate resource for something like x:Name="HoveredUserIcon".

I'd like to have a simpler workflow overall but, at the very least, I'd like to solve the coloring issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at StateGroups:

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/06/10/visual-state

It's actually very easy to make minor deviations of your control and have it work the way you intend.

There's a nice little video on this blog that walks through using Expression Blend to do this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2009/10/02/visual-state-manager-tips-for-design-and-authoring.aspx

Comment: I'm privy to StateGroups and the VSM, but would that help me in this specific case? Even if I give the path a name can I target it and its Fill property? It's inside the <ContentTemplate> in a <DataTemplate> (where, apparently, TemplateBinding is not available). I've only ever manipulated elements that were directly inside the <Template> element of a control; and where, yes, I've successfully utilized the VSM.

Comment: You know what? I got the solution for using vectors for a button icon elsewhere on the internets. Turns out you can put the path directly in the template and where TemplateBinding works just fine. Thanks for the help anyway.